# How can I synchronize Android UI drawing with Vulkan rendering?

Tags: android, vulkan

The goal is to keep Android UI layer content pixel-aligned w/ Vulkan-rendered content. We have looked at using Choreographer and attempting to compensate for frame delay, however, either the Vulkan thread can get ahead of Android UI, or vice versa, and we have not found any appropriate backpressure source for the UI. We've looked at Swappy, VK_GOOGLE_display_timing, and others, but the key missing aspect is the linkage between dispatching draw to Vulkan/Android and ensuring that pixels arrive on screen at the same time.

Comment: Have you considered bypassing the Android UI and drawing with Vulkan entirely?

Comment: Yes, this is one of the options we're considering. Unfortunately, it seems like that may be necessary for 1:1 sync: https://twitter.com/compassing/status/1532123379452456961